# Is it permissible to assign the ALL the proceeds of an anticipated judgement to the lawyer(s)?

Tags: contract-law, intellectual-property, ohio

In the case of an artisan group that only wants to redeem its good name, and to get back to work,
is is allowed to motivate attornies by assigning them all the proceeds of an anticipated judgement?

Comment: This does seem like a question best posited to the lawyer themselves.  It is unlikely that they would lie under the circumstances where they have much to gain or that they would risk breaking the law in addition to withholding importance relevant advice from their client (if it is against the law).  ***However,*** this is probably a good exception to the "don't ask for legal advice" rule.  A good answer can only inform the OP and the community about relevant laws.  It is not likely that it would discourage the user from seeking professional advice from their own lawyer.

Comment: What happens if the artisan group loses the case? Do they purport that the attorneys get nothing?

Comment: That's right. An attorney who would lose this case is precisely what we prefer to avoid.

Comment: There is ample avidence, well organized. An attorney should be able to ascertain if the case accords with the letter of the law. An attorney who would charge the client good money only to lose, would NOT deserve to earn 100% of the judgement proceeds.

Comment: @grovkin We were told by a lawyer in Tallahassee Florida that Bar ethics forbids an attorney to receive 100% the proceeds of a judgement. He may have invented this for the purpose of brushing us off (¿)  Wouldnt it be preferable to know beforehand? ...so as to not seem to be such an ignorant person if this practice is illegal or considered unethical.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz well, if they don't want to do something for 100% of the money, they probably don't want to do it for 1/3 of that amount, either.  But there could be other reasons a lawyer doesn't want such a client.  For example, a client who doesn't expect a monetary payout at the end of the process may, with time, lose interest in the outcome and become a less enthusiastic participant in the undertaking.

Comment: "a client who doesn't expect a monetary payout at the end of the process may, with time, lose interest in the outcome and become a less enthusiastic participant in the undertaking" Not us! Our interest is in vindication that we have been the truthful ones.
If the lawyer makes a fortune that won't bother us. On the contrary! Money is dangerous. It causes social differences in our village society. Money atracts criminals.  we will assist the lawyer in any way we can, in order that our tormentors are punished and we can return to our rightful place in the market with our good name re-estabished.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [contingency fees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingent_fee) approach is, also known as "no win no fee".

> We were told by a lawyer in Tallahassee Florida that Bar ethics forbids an attorney to receive 100% the proceeds of a judgement.

That's correct. From the linked Wikipedia article:

> Most jurisdictions require contingent fees to be "reasonable," resulting in a typical contingent fee of 33-45% of any eventual recovery.

That said, the fact that the attorney did not mention that they could possibly receive 33-45% instead of 100% probably speaks of their lack of interest (which in turn could speak of the prospects of winning).

But it'll certainly worth trying more attorneys.

Comment: The Tallahassee Florida lawyer never reviewed the evidence, so the prospect of winning was not a factor. He is a personal injury lawyer so it was not his area of expertise, He did provide us the name of a high-powered Lanham Act attorney in Fort Lauderdale who immediately dismissed our contact, likewise without reviewing the case or the evidence.

Comment: That was Florida. Can we offer 100% of judgement in Ohio or Delaware? Truthfully, we are not interested in the judgment money (even if it were a lot). We want the truth to be known and to curtail this noxious practice of pretending to benefit craftspeople. Most of all to vindicate ourselves and to reclaim our good name and come again into direct contact with the Fair Trade retailers while eliminating the vicious commercial inermediary.  We are traditional artisans. Money does not interest us. What interests us is work; reestablishing our rightful place in the market to enjoy employment income.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz If you're so confident that you have a winning case, why not to offer to pay fees regardless of the outcome plus say 40% contingency? Lawyers may be repelled as soon as they hear you are paying no fees but 100% contingency.

Comment: We don't want or need "lawyers who may be repelled", only one lawyer who is ambitious for money,

Comment: As jewelry producers over the past 50+ years, we know that money is not needed to capitalize a  viable cottage craft industry. When the buyers can re-sell our products for multiples of six-ten times, they fall over themselves to pre-pay production orders; that is how the local industry has grown to more than 30 thousand+ families during its peak period in the 1970's and 1980's. There was no bank or government financing, no 'foreign investment'. Then, commerical buyers  physically came here to get us to make the abalone jewlery or .925 silver jewelry they knew they could profitably re-sell.

Comment: Also, big sums of money can be very dangerous! attracting criminals and/or causing disunity in our group. We would just as soon the attorney makes a fortune when it has been established that our position has been thoroughly vindicated and that we have always been the truthful ones; when vile calumnies secretely circulated against our perfectly good name have been unquestinably discredited, so when our traditional customers in the USA discover the real situation they will 'prefer' us to the cynical commecial middlemen who pretend to represent us and be our benefactors.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz Virtually all lawyers are ambitious for money, that's why they want guaranteed pay per hours worked, and only _then_ may consider contingency bonus — no matter how big. They can't be enticed just by an opportunity to invest their time and effort for only a _potential_ prize in return (especially that they may not see the potential as you do).

Comment: We are not looking for 'lawyers' who are likely to lose. A single ambitious lawyer will do.

Comment: Our antagonists are like the student Raskolnikov burning with fever to run from his conscience, fainting at the Police Station (It was only a notice;  he was behind on his rent!); heightened awarness of their wrongdoing as a factor. In 2021, this business was sold to the stockgirl. In 2020, it moved from Florida to Ohio to put more distance between us. There exist an elitist mentality that simply is incapable of imagining that a few powerless women in the 3rdworld would never climb out of the ditch and pursue their fancy carriage. Luckily, we are easy. They could negotiate a good deal with us.